# laravel mass assignment with extra field

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

It's My **Store** Method In **Post Controller**

```
$post = Post::create($request->all());
$post->author()->associate(auth()->user()); // or $post->author_id=auth()->id;
```

By MassAssignment , There is two query. Is there any alternative way to do action in only one query?

Answer (score 2):

```
$post = Post::create(['author_id' => auth()->id] + $request->all());
```

Comment: so I should put author_id in fillable . yeah?

Comment: by doing this, user can inject author_id in update request

Comment: yes, add this field to. Javad Ali right, change $request->all() + ['author_id' => auth()->id] to ['author_id' => auth()->id] +  $request->all()

Answer (score 0):

Use the reverse relation

`Auth::user()->posts()->create($request->all());`

On your user class you need to have the reverse definition of the relationship

```
public function posts() {
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

Comment: what if there is two extra field? author_id , blog_id (which is in query string)

Comment: The you cannot go around adding them in fillable. However you might want to think about not passing that through the query string since it is pretty insecure (Or check if the user has access/is allowed etc. in the controller)